# how to "ident_current" in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I use this code in MSSQL:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('customers');
```

When I try it in MySQL it doesn't work. I looked for answers on the net, but I could not find anything that worked for me. What's the MySQL equivalent for the above TSQL?

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID('customers');
```

But `LAST_INSERT_ID()` not in all cases true, so better use:

```
SELECT MAX('id') FROM customers;
```

Comment: you were right, the last_insert_id doesn't work for me. what if i delete the last row: the id of the last row was 6, delete it, and then "select max('customerID') from customers", will it 6 or 5 because I deleted the last row with the id 6?

Comment: if u select max it will be the selected id from the table , so it will be 5. the max will be from the table, the max is always true and it selects from the table

Comment: than how could i get the next id, that will be in the auto increment? for example, i have already these ids: 1,2,4,5,6. I delete the last, than i will have: 1,2,4,5. if i would insert a new row, the new row's id would be 7!! but i don't want to insert a new row, only i want is get the next id from the auto increment.

Comment: u want if u create new row it will be 6 ?

Comment: if i delete the row with id=6, than i create a new row (i don't have to give the id's number because of the auto increment), than the new id will be 7, not 6, so the ids will be: 1,2,4,5,7

Comment: i want to get the next id's number! i don't want to create a new row (id=7), i only want to get the next id's number! "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('customers');" in mssql would give me the 6, than i can give it plusz 1, and than i would have the 7. but in mysql..?

Comment: in mysql , if u delete the id =6 , and u create new row id=7 , then when u use select max , it will give u the row id =7 .

Comment: and if i delete the row with id 7, than i create a new row, the new id will be 8!! because of the autoincrement! i said i don't want to create new rows, only get the new id's number, that would be in the auto increment

Comment: yes its like that the autoincrement. if u insert new data then the id will be incremented by 1 .

Comment: you don't understand me... i know the auto increment.. new example: i delete every row. than how could i get the last inserted (auto increment) id? because the MAX(id) will give me 0, but the autoincrement will create new row with 7! (if the 6 was the last). so i only want to get the number the last AUTO INCREMENTED id!

Comment: sorry i didnt understnd u , try to ask new question. hope i could answer on how to select the last inserted id.

Answer (score 3):

in MySQL, you can use `LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)`

- [LAST_INSERT_ID(expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: doesn't work for me, I have a tabla with 3 rows, the last row's ID is 3, and this SQL gives me "1"..

Comment: @victorio The MySQL LAST_INSERT_ID function returns the first AUTO_INCREMENT value that was set by the most recent INSERT or UPDATE statement that affected an AUTO_INCREMENT column.

Answer (score 2):

I don´t know if you still need it but it may help someone. :)

I was facing the same problem of needing to get the next id (auto_increment number) from my table without having to add a new row and without using MAX() or LAST_INSERT_ID() because it would only return the last visible record and not the real next auto_increment.

The solution I found was to get the auto_increment from the table_schema, like this:

```
SELECT  AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM    information_schema.TABLES
WHERE   (TABLE_NAME = 'your_table')
```

Hope it help someone, like it helped me.
*Sorry the bad english, I'm from Brasil.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

To learn more about this function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

In order for this to work as intended, the 'ID' column must be set to "UNIQUE".

Answer (score -1):

If you are using some sort of Identity(incrementing IDs) column the following should work;

```
Select top 1 ID from TBLNAME
order by ID DESC
```

Comment: what if i delete the last row? than the top 1 ID will be the before-last row, not the deleted, but i need the id, that would be the next in auto increment